# How I can find the speed in mph from latitude, longitude and time stamp in sql?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have table and which store the data like GPS timestamp, vehicle, GPS latitude, longitude, and altitude.

The GPS timestamp is updating at every second.

I would like to write the query to find out that identifies speeders (anyone flying over 500mph).

Also, I would like to find the record have distance less then 50 feet away from any other with each direction?

Is there any function available so I can perform quick operation on SQL database as I have 50 million car records per day.

Comment: check [SQL Server Spatial Data](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb933790.aspx)

Comment: @JuanCarlosOropeza spatial data types are 2 dimensional at best. The OP needs 3 dimensions.

Comment: @Shadow I think you can reference three `dimensional` point as show [here](https://www.simple-talk.com/sql/t-sql-programming/introduction-to-sql-server-spatial-data/). Even mention a 4th dimension but dont know what is that for.

Comment: And then you do what with it? Stdistance() ignores the elevation coordinate as far as I know. So, you have to calculate the distances manually. Therefore it does not really matter if you just simply store the 3 coordinates in 3 columns or you use a geography point data type.

Answer (score 1):

If possible, you're better off trying to calculate those values in code, before they hit the database. Obviously that's dependant on you being able to catch the records beforehand.

50 million records daily is going to result in a huge amount of data to crunch, and if you need to check for speeders on every transaction (each second, for N vehicles), the queries are going to be unmanageable. That's my opinion, at least.